# Bad request while trying to upload file using Box API

Tags: box-api

I am new to Box API. I am trying to upload a file, I get bad request.

This is the url I am trying to hit https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content

request body is {"name" : "gg-1.jpg", "parent" : {"id": "0"} } // as I am trying to add file on the root in this call

also header is proper {Authorization: Bearer xxxxx} //xxxxx is some proper refresh token

It throws Bad request error.

Can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Can you shown us any of the code you're using to make the request?

Comment: What does error message say ? Response should contains a more descriptive message.

Comment: @BorisSuvorov I get only this - 
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Do you see any issue with my request params or the upload url that I am trying to hit?

Comment: @Ashish name/parent seems to be sufficient according to documentation. how do you supplying file info (multipart?)? have you tried Curl command as per documentation?

Comment: @BorisSuvorov I don't use mutlipart. I write my file stream to request stream. I haven't tried curl command.. Looks like I will have to try curl.

Comment: https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file says you have to use a multipart post to do uploads

Comment: thanks guys! got it working.. realize that I need to go with multipart post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356380/peter) suggested, multi-part was the solution.

developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file